# Given an acyclic directed graph, return a collection of collections of nodes "at the same level"?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, graph-theory, networkx

Firstly I am not sure what such an algorithm is called, which is the primary problem - so first part of the question is what is this algorithm called?

Basically I have a `DiGraph()` into which I insert the nodes `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` and the edges `([1,3],[2,3],[3,5],[4,5],[5,7],[6,7],[7,8],[7,9],[7,10])`

From this I'm wondering if it's possible to get a collection as follows: `[[1, 2, 4, 6], [3], [5], [7], [8, 9, 10]]`

EDIT: Let me add some constraints if it helps.
- There are no cycles, this is guaranteed
- There is no one start point for the graph

What I'm trying to do is to collect the nodes at the same level such that their processing can be parallelized, but within the outer collection, the processing is serial.

EDIT2: So clearly I hadn't thought about this enough, so the easiest way to describe "level" is interms of *deepest predecessor*, all nodes that have the same depth of predecessors. So the first entry in the above list are all nodes that have 0 as the deepest predecessor, the second has one, third has two and so on. Within each list, the order of the *siblings* is irrelevant as they will be parallelly processed.

Comment: *BFS*, Breadth First Search? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: What you're asking for seems to make a number of assumptions about the graph structure (for instance, that there is at most only one path from any node to any other node).  What would you expect the collection to be if you add the edge `[1, 2]` to your graph?

Comment: I've modified the title to try to reflect the intent of your question more accurately. Hope I didn't misunderstand ...

Comment: Can you clearly define what a "level" is?  What if there is an edge (1,2) and some other edges (3,4) and (4,2).  What are the collections you want?  Is

Comment: @joel, is that any clearer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question states that you would like the output, for this graph, to be `[[1, 2, 4, 6], [3], [5], [7], [8, 9, 10]]`. IIUC, the pattern is as follows:

- `[1, 2, 4, 6]` are the nodes that have no in edges.
- `[3]` are the nodes that have no in edges, assuming all previous nodes were erased.
- `[4]` are the nodes that have no in edges, assuming all previous nodes were erased.
- Etc. (until all nodes have been erased)

Say we start with

```
g = networkx.DiGraph()
g.add_edges_from([[1,3],[2,3],[3,5],[4,5],[5,7],[6,7],[7,8],[7,9],[7,10]])
```

Then we can just code this as

```
def find_levels(g):
    levels = []
    while g.nodes():
        no_in_nodes = [n for (n, d) in g.in_degree(g.nodes()).items() if d == 0]
        levels.append(no_in_nodes)
        for n in no_in_nodes:
            g.remove_node(n)
    return levels
```

If we run this, we get the result:

```
>>> find_levels(g)
[[1, 2, 4, 6], [3], [5], [7], [8, 9, 10]]
```

The complexity here is *Θ(|V|<sup>2</sup> + |E|)*. A somewhat more complicated version can be built using a [Fibonnacci Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap#Summary_of_running_times). Basically, all vertices need to be placed into a heap, with each level consisting of the vertices with 0 in degree. Each time one is popped, and the edges to other vertices are removed, we can translate this to a heap decrease-key operation (the in-degrees of remaining vertices are reduced). This would reduce the running time to *Θ(|V| log(|V|) + |E|)*.

Comment: the problem here is the nodes can't be removed, when you look at `1` for example, the "level" of 3/5/7 changes..

Comment: Thanks for that input, but, I've decided to take a slightly different approach which is to keep an attribute at each node indicating it's level. As I add new nodes and rearrange the tree, I walk the successors and track the max depth. Kind of like Charles's answer below. Normally these operations should be fairly infrequent. The most common operation is evaluating the tree and your second approach is too expensive, a topological sort followed by a single pass through the tree looked ng at the attribute will allow me to do exactly what I need..

Comment: Sorry - I thought it could be simplified further - but I was wrong. As I said above though, by storing the additional state, I can get around not having to destroy the graph..

Comment: @Nim Sure, whatever works for you. I'd just like to point out that the most efficient implementation of which I'm aware is the one at the end of my answer using a Fibonnacci heap. That one does not require destroying the graph, but rather just adding an attribute to each edge (indicating whether it has been already discarded as emanating from a used vertex).

Answer (score 2):

A topological sort will achieve this, as Ami states. The following is a Boost Graph Library implementation, with no context, but the pseudocode can be extracted. The `toporder` object just provides the iterator to a topological ordering. I can extract the general algorithm if desired.

```
template<typename F>
void 
scheduler<F>::set_run_levels()
{

  run_levels = std::vector<int>(tasks.size(), 0);
  Vertexcont toporder;

  try
    {
      topological_sort(g, std::front_inserter(toporder));
    }
  catch(std::exception &e)
    {
      std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
      std::cerr << "You most likely have a cycle...\n";
      exit(1);
    }

  vContIt i = toporder.begin();

  for(;
      i != toporder.end();
      ++i)
    {
      if (in_degree(*i,g) > 0)
        {
          inIt j, j_end;
          int maxdist = 0;
          for(boost::tie(j,j_end) = in_edges(*i,g);
              j != j_end;
              ++j)
            {
              maxdist = (std::max)(run_levels[source(*j,g)], maxdist);
              run_levels[*i] = maxdist+1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think I once applied this to the same problem, then realized it was unnecessary. Just set up the tasks on a hair-trigger, with all tasks signaling completion to their dependents (by a condition_variable, promise). So all I needed was to know the dependencies of each task, find the initial task, then fire. Is a full specification of `run_level` needed in your case?

Comment: Interesting! The question was tagged as `networkx`, but I'm looking forward to going over your code and seeing how to do this in the BGL.

Comment: I was trying to avoid too much state in the tree, but it seems holding a `run_level` combined with a topological sort helps me process the tree in a single pass, then I don't need the countdown latch as you describe, I know then when I get to the next run level all nodes prior has been evaluated..

Answer (score 0):

Why would bfs not solve it? A bfs algorithm is breadth traversal algorithm, i.e. it traverses the tree level wise. This also means, all nodes at same level are traversed at once, which is your desired output.
As pointed out in comment, this will however, assume a starting point in the graph.

Comment: The thing about BFS is that it assumes some starting node, while the question seems to want to get these node sets as information about the graph as a whole.

Comment: @brenbarn: first create the graph G', which consists of all the nodes and edges of G plus a new node n' with edges n'->q for every node q in G with in-degree 0. (You can do that in O(|E+N|) by adding n'->q for all q, then making a pass over all edges and removing the head of the edge from the set of added edges.) If there are no edges addes, the graph is cyclic and the concept of the "level" of a node is a bit odd. You could, however, use Tarjan's algorithm to identify the SCCs, and then create the augmented graph from the induced graph of SCCs.

Comment: You can do it with a BFS, but it's not as simple as your answer implies. Specifically, the statement that *"all nodes at the same level are traversed at once"* is false. For example, there are multiple ways to get to node 7. The possible paths are {1,3,5,7}, {2,3,5,7}, {4,5,7}, and {6,7}. So the BFS will find node 7 at levels 2,3, and 4. The correct level for node 7 is 4. So the BFS needs to keep track of the deepest level where any node was found. (Of course, you also need to find the starting nodes before the BFS can begin, as already mentioned.)